# How can I pass a JSON body which contains an array in wso2 Integration studio Payload Factory mediator

Tags: postman, wso2, integration, payload

**I have a JSON body and need to pass it in the payload**

```
{
  "customerId": 1,
  "productId": 1,
  "productProperties": [
    {
      "propertyCd": "XYZ",
      "propertyValue": "12"
    }
  ],
  "tierId": 1,
  "tierPlanPriceId": 1
}
```

**Below is the source code I am trying:**

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{
  "customerId": $1,
  "productId": $2,
  "productProperties": [
    {
      "propertyCd": "$3",
      "propertyValue": "$4"
    }
  ],
  "tierId": $5,
  "tierPlanPriceId": $6
}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.customerId"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.productId"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.productProperties[0].propertyCd"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.productProperties[0].propertyValue"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.tierId"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.tierPlanPriceId"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
 I  <send>
            <endpoint key="AddQuatationEP"/>
        </send>
```

**After calling the API I am getting the response as Product properties is null.**

Could you please help to resolve this issue? How can I pass the properties array in the payload factory mediator?

Comment: Can you share your input payload as well